# PragmaticWorks/SentryOne Task Factory REST source SSIS setup

Tags: rest, ssis, google-ads-api, taskfactory

I'm trying to set up a REST source in SSIS using Task Factory's tool. I'm trying to get data from Google Adwords using this endpoint:

https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/reportdownload/v201806

I need to send in some parameters in the post and there is a box in this tool for "Post Data", but I am unsure how to format this data.

[image]

The message that I'm getting is:

> ReportDownloadError.MISSING_PARAMETER
>       Missing report definition

I'm not sure what the report definition is or where to put it. Or how to add the post data to the post data box. Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

The POST body for a report request must be form-encoded. I'm not sure how to achieve this in Task Factory, but your request's body should looks like this:

```
__rdquery=SELECT+CampaignId%2C+AdGroupId%2C+Impressions%2C+Clicks%2C+Cost+FROM+ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT+WHERE+AdGroupStatus+IN+%5BENABLED%2C+PAUSED%5D+DURING+LAST_7_DAYS&__fmt=CSV
```